# Benefits of TLS over SSL3

Tags: security, ssl

Can someone tell me what are the benefits of TLS over SSL3? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TLS is a standard (defined in RFC). TLS 1.0 could be considered SSL 3.1. Now there exists TLS 1.2. [TLS 1.0](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2246.txt) brought only minor (but breaking) changes. You will find the list of additions in the RFC for [TLS 1.1](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4346.txt) (section 1.1) and [TLS 1.2](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5246.txt) (section 1.2).

Also there were several additions defined in separate RFCs, e.g. AES support, Camellia support, compression, etc. All of these features are not available in SSL, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I think Server Name Indication Option is the most useful when comparing TLS over SSL which could make you install more than one certificate in one IP address, which means VirtualHost